# Why Spring Boot controller test returning 404, but controller found in context?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit5

I've got a REST controller I'm trying to test, but when attempting to POST to it, I get a 404. The test is JUnit 5 and Spring Boot 2.1.5. If I run the application, I can hit the controller via Postman. I've run it in debug mode and verified that `myController` is not null and has the mocked services injected into it. What am I missing here? spring-boot-starter-test is a dependency, and junit4 is an exclusion.

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
@RequestMapping(path = /integrations,
    produces = "application/json")
public class MyController {

    private MyService myService;
    private MyValidationService myValidationService;

    public MyController(MySerivce service, MyValidationService myValidationService) {
        this.myService = service;
        this.myValidationService = myValidationService;
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/users", produces = "application/json", consumes = 
                                       "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<User> getUserList(@Valid @RequestBody final RequestPayload 
          requestPayload, @RequestHeader Map<String, String> headers) throws MyException {
        // check the credentials and permission
        Map<String, String> credInfo = myValidationService.validateHeaders(headers);

        // process payload
        return myService.retrieveUsers(requestPayload);


    }
}
```

Test is as follows:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class MyControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    private MyService myService;

    @MockBean
    private MyValidationService myValidationService;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    MyController myController;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() throws Exception {
        Assert.assertNotNull(myController);
    }

    @Test
    void getUserList() throws Exception {
        List<User> users = returnUserList();
        HttpEntity<RequestPayload> requestHttpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(returnPayload(), null);
        when(myService.retrieveUsers(any(RequestPayload.class))).thenReturn(users);
        mockMvc.perform(post("/integrations/users")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(asJsonString(returnPayload()))
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful());

    }
}
```

The response I get is:

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 404
    Error message = null
          Headers = []
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

Comment: Is this end point is working when you normally start spring boot application ?

Comment: Yes, it works under normal operation.

Comment: @Deadpool we're on the same page. Tried it, but same result.

Comment: @Deadpool I'll try to pull something together. I basically simplified the real code. I just also updated versions of junit5-jupiter and mockito. Changed the 2nd line to `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)

@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
`

Comment: Nope. No change. Shot in the dark!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appreciate the answers, but I discovered what the problem was - and it was a bonehead one!

It turns out that I included the context path in the mockMvc call when that value is already provided in the *application.properties* file! So instead of a URI of */integrations/users*, the real URI being used was */integrations/integrations/users*, which unsurprisingly does not exist!

Thanks to all and sorry for not taking my eyes in my hands and looking more closely.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a slice test annotation instead. For testing a controller you can use @WebMvcTest.

Your setup would look like this:

```
@SpringBootTest(value = MyController.class)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class MyControllerTest {
```

You can still @Autowired the MockMvc. Also there is no need to autowire your controller in the test.